# How to select outer line segments

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

I am having 2D line segments. My goal is to make different closed polygons. But, in here, I want to select most outer line segments when there are few parallel line segments stay closed to each other. with different line combinations, I can make different closed polygons.I was thinking and struggling to know how to get most outer lines as I need the polygon which make by outer most lines. (Polyogns are at the end constructed by intersecting adjoying line segments.)
I was thinking to get a large bounding box containing all segments and get the centroid and then find the perpendicular distances to each line. In this process, I found nearby line segments which oriented close to each other (i.e. near parallel lines). So, from those nearby parallel lines I want outer most one. (that is red one).
But If I used the centroid and compare the distnaces, then longest distance (among nearby parallel lines) does not give correct outer most line when more concave and convex turns exist as some cases outer most (red) one does not give by the longest distance. What I have is; end point coordinates of each line segments. (that is vector data)

> So, I am looking for some good way to get most outer line segments from nearby parallel lines.
>   For you to understand I have attached a sample data which i have. The most outer line segments are shown in red color. finally this red lines give me the boundary of my polygon. So, I want to get red lines out of corresponding nearby parallel black lines.

NOTE: My line segments are oriented into different direction. And not only to X & Y axes. Also, nearby lines donot make always 90 or 180 angles with adjacent lines.

please suggest me a method. thanks in advance

for example, if A,B and C,D are nearby parallel line segments. then outer most line should be B and C. But, If i compare distances from centroid (O), then I can get C as outer most, but B can not get as distance from O to B is smaller than O to A. My method fails in this type of spots. So, look alternatives..

[image]

Comment: do you have only lines parallel to axis ?

Comment: @Grigor Gevorgyan: no, my lines are not always parallel to XY axes. some are oblique to axes.

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you mean with "the outer line segments". Do you mean the outer ones per group nearby parallel lines? Or the outer lines of the entire polygon?

Comment: In order to this make sense you need to do the following: describe the exact operation you want to perform, "outer line segments" is not a good description. After doing that, be nice and include the output of the input example based on this exact description.

Comment: I will update the post soon. sorry for the inconveniences

Comment: @Wouter van Nifterick: yes correct. outer most lines are shown in red color.

Comment: @mmgp: my output should be selection of all red lines out of other lines.

Comment: @niro you are missing the most important information: the exact description of what you want. Part of your problem is caused because you don't know what you want to achieve. For instance, consider the red lines at top right (not sure if it is clear without explicitly showing them myself). How are you going to form a part of a polygon with them ? It also seems you would cut through a line segment at the top left corner in order to make any polygon.

Comment: @mmgp: sorry, Not sure i got your point. But I rearrange my post. Hope it would clear now. thanks

Answer (score 1):

A general way to find lines is using the Hough Transform.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform

However, the sample data you give has lines parallel to the axes.  I don't know if that is the nature of all of your data, but if it is then the Hough Transform basically breaks down to simply summing up the intensities by rows for lines parallel to the x-axis and summing by columns for lines parallel to the y-axis.

You will end up with two 1D arrays, one with row sums and one with column sums.  Since the lines are black and the foreground is white, local minimums in these arrays will represent line locations along each axis.  Since you only need the outer lines, you do not have to sum every column/row - just start at the edges of the image and compute the sums until you hit a local min. Once you have the line's placement on the axis, you can traverse that cut of the axis in the image to find the endpoints of the line.

Comment: My data are in vector format. because of the confusion, I update my image.

Comment: I see.  If that's the case then this isn't a suitable answer... perhaps you should remove the image-processing tag?